# Gmail HTML length limit

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

## Question

Do you know if their is an html limit size with Gmail to keep the mail preview (in pixel or in number of characters) ?

---

## Origin of the question

In the picture below:

- The email received at 15:38 is display as ...
- The email received at 15:46 is displayed in the preview.

The only difference is the size of the mail content.

[image]

---

Eventually, if it could help, the html of the 15:38 mail

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #efefef; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
      <table class="body-wrap" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Avenir Next', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.65; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #efefef; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
         <tr>
            <td class="container" style="display: block; clear: both; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px;">
               <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" class="masthead" style="padding: 10px 0; background: #C50929; color: white;">
                        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.25; font-size: 32px; max-width: 90%; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 auto;">IDÉAL CARGO<br>Trailer demand</h1>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="content" style="background: white; padding: 10px 35px;">
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.25; font-size: 24px;">Customer request</h3>
                        <table class="display_info" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                           <tr style="color: #666B85; border-top: none;">
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Trailer </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px; background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Classic </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Zone </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Sport Zone </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Dealer </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px; background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> ATTACHES CHATEAUGUAY </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Question </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Blablabla aljfn uh iq fiqbef jhbh hh qjhe bwrh piv paiueh fak zcyb hzph paub ya pbh au dhalsk pvy^tefs </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Name </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px; background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Grand schtroumpf </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Email </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> abec@gmail.com </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85;">
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Phone </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px; background: #EBEBEB;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> 123 456 789 </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1; color: #666B85; border-bottom: none;">
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> City </p>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;">
                                 <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;"> Las vegas </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="container" style="display: block; clear: both; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px;">
               <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                     <td class="content footer" align="center" style="padding: 10px 35px; background: none;">
                        <p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 0; color: #888; text-align: center;"> Send by<a href="http://www.idealtrailer.com/" style="color: #888; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;"> Idéal Cargo</a></p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The email received at 15:38 is display as "..." because Gmail merge emails nearly received with the same subject. Try to change the subject if you have to do test.

Anyway, Gmail has a max size limit of the HTML that it seems be 102KB.